# Java count pattern in String

Tags: java

Lets say you have a method which takes in a pattern and also an entire String...

The method looks like this:

```
public int count(String pattern, String input) { 
    int count = 0;
    // How to implement the number of occurrences of the pattern?
}
```

So, the inputs could be this:

```
String input = "sdbwedfddfbcaeeudhsomeothertestddtfdonemoredfdsatdevdb";

String pattern = "ddt";

int result = count(pattern, input);
```

What would be the most efficient way (in terms of complexity) to iterate and find the occurrences of "ddt"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to achieve that is to `split` the `String` according to the given `pattern`:

```
int result = input.split(pattern,-1).length - 1;
```

**How It Works:**

```
.split(pattern, -1)  -> split the String into an array according to the pattern given, -1 (negative limit) means the pattern will be applied as many times as possible.
.length  -> take the length of the array
-1 -> the logic requires counting the splitter (i.e. pattern), so if there is only one occurrence, that will split it into two , when subtract 1 -> it gives the count
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes, e.g.:

```
public int count(String pattern, String input) { 
    int count = 0;
    Pattern patternObject = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = patternObject.matcher(input);
    while(matcher.find()){
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
public int count(String pattern, String input) { 
    int i = (input.length()-input.replace(pattern, "").length())/pattern.length();
    return i;
}
```

Or even shorter

```
public int count(String pattern, String input) { 
    return (input.split(pattern, -1).length-1);
}
```